# Smooth Scroll Implementation Using Image Mapped Navigation Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, smooth-scrolling

I'm currently trying to use smooth scrolling on a site, but with a fixed navigation bar that has been image mapped. Unfortunately, this appears to make using anchors impossible. I'm also using sections, which look like they cannot be named as anchors.

Additionally, whenever I have tried implementing any jquery version of smooth scroll I can find, it does not work. Can anyone explain how to format the code into HTML5?

```
<style type='text/css'>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
        section {
            display: block;
            background: #6699ff;
            height: 2000px;
        }
        .header-cont {
            width: 100%;
            position: relative;
            top: 0px;
            text-align: center;
            padding-top: 15px;
        }
        .header {
            margin: 0px auto;
        }
        .navbar-cont {
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            position: fixed;
            top: 160px;
            z-index: 10000;
        }
        .navbar {
            margin: 0px auto;
        }
        .content-a {
            width: 100%;
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
            padding-top: 90px;
        }
        </style>

<body>
    <div class='navbar-cont'>
        <div class ='navbar'>
            <img src='NavBar.png' alt ='Navigation Bar' width="619" height="48" usemap="#NavMap"/>
            <map id="NavMap" name="NavMap">
                <area shape ="rect" coords ="1,0,70,48" href="#" alt="Home"/>
                <area shape ="rect" coords ="76,0,150,48" href="#News" alt="News"/>
                <area shape ="rect" coords ="158,0,264,48" href="#AboutUs" alt="About Us"/>
                <area shape ="rect" coords ="270,0,370,48" href="#Contact" alt="Contact"/>
                <area shape ="rect" coords ="375,0,450,48" href="#Music" alt="Music"/>
                <area shape ="rect" coords ="455,0,550,48" href="#Photos" alt="Photos"/>
                <area shape ="rect" coords ="555,0,615,48" href="#Links" alt="Links"/>
            </map>
        </div>
    </div>
    <section id='Home'>
        <div class='header-cont'>
            <div class='header'>
                <header>
                    <img src='SkycoLogoHeader.png' alt='Skyco Logo'/>
                </header>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content-a">
            <img src="HomeText.png" alt="Home Text"/>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id='News'>
        <div class='header-cont'>
            <div class='header'>
                <img src='SkycoNewsHeader.png' alt='News'/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id='AboutUs'>
        <div class="header-cont">
            <div class="header">
                <img src="SkycoAboutHeader.png" alt="About Us"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id='Contact'>
        <div class="header-cont">
            <div class="header">
                <img src="SkycoContactHeader.png" alt="Contact"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id='Music'>
        <div class="header-cont">
            <div class="header">
                <img src="SkycoMusicHeader.png" alt="Music"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id='Photos'>
        <div class="header-cont">
            <div class="header">
                <img src="SkycoPhotosHeader.png" alt="Photos"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id='Links'>
        <div class="header-cont">
            <div class="header">
                <img src="SkycoLinksHeader.png" alt="Links"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

The script I have been using:

```
 <script>
            var jump=function(e)
{
   e.preventDefault();
   var target = $(this).attr("href");
   $('html,body').animate(
   {
           scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
   },2000,function()
   {
           location.hash = target;
   });

}

$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('a[href*=#]').bind("click", jump);
   return false;
});
        </script>
```

Comment: please try adding a fiddle with relevant images, I tried adding it but of course I don't have your images which are central to this question. Also, I'm betting "Nav Bar.png" is the root of your problem, try to use names with no spaces, or use HTML entities, like Nav%20Bar.png

Comment: @Fabio 

I'm not entirely sure how to go about making this into a fiddle.

That being said, I took all spaces out of the PNG names and the smooth scroll still does not work. I'm trying to use an image that has been mapped as a navigation bar, which appears to limit my use of the anchor system.

Comment: well, without seeing more or knowing about your script, it's hard to tell, but I can't imagine any scenario in which an image map affects the anchors or jQuery, so the issue has to be somewhere else

Comment: @Fabio I have added the script I've been using to the post above. The image mapping is preventing me from using the <a> tag. I cannot put it before the <area> tags or the links no longer work, and it cannot go within the <area> tags. Therefore, the image mapping appears to affect how the script is being handled.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Then try this:

First of all, enclose everything but your nav bar inside a div, main or section tag. Like this:

```
<div class="main">
</div>
```

Now, in your JS change this line

```
$('a[href*=#]').bind("click", jump);
```

to

```
$('.main a[href*=#]').bind("click", jump);
```

Comment: What settings should there be for the "main" class? Are you saying I can enclose everything before the first "<section id=" into a single div with the class "main"?

Comment: Alright, and the settings for the "main" class? I've tried .main {position: relative;} with the div as you mentioned and the smooth scrolling is not working.

Comment: Any more ideas? I still cannot seem to get the scroll to work

Comment: no, sorry, if this doesn't work then I have no idea what can be wrong. Also, I have to work on my own stuff, so maybe someone else can give you some pointers

Comment: So this website is somehow impossible to build? There is no conceivable way to implement smooth scrolling into this code? You also never recommended what the style settings should be for the "main" class you suggested.